# Cmake : how to append string to the variable via command line?

Tags: c++, cmake

In my CMakeList.txt i can do the following thing:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -new -flags -here")
```

Is it possible to to the same thing via command line? Like:

```
cmake.exe -DCMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -new -flags
```

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -new -flags -here")` You want to copy the C_FLAGS to the CXX_FLAGS or is this a typo?

Comment: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXXFLAGS="${CMAKE_CXXFLAGS} -new -flags"` should work

Comment: just a typo;
cmake -DCMAKE_CXXFLAGS="${CMAKE_CXXFLAGS} -new -flags" doesn't work

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure whether you can directly add options from the command line, but you can use an additional variable to store them and merge it at the end. Like the following:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${MY_FLAGS}")
```

And then call cmake as following:

```
cmake -DMY_FLAGS="-new -flags"
```

Comment: When I try to add the flag `/DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` like this, CMake interprets the flag as a relative path and instead adds `C:/Program Files/Git/DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`. How can I prevent that?

Comment: A workaround that I found worked was to use `-DMY_FLAGS=' /DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB'` instead of `-DMY_FLAGS='/DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB'` (note the added space before the flag).

Comment: what about `list(APPEND ... ` ?

Answer (score 14):

First of all, keep your hands off `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`! Use [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html):

```
target_compile_options(<YOUR_TARGET> PRIVATE ${MY_FLAGS})
```

To expand other lists use [`list`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/list.html):

```
list(APPEND <YOUR_LIST> <ITEM_TO_ADD>)
```

Comment: What if `<YOUR_TARGET>` is not *your* target, and you can't modify it?

Comment: @rustyx Why can't you ever update a target? You can always create your own target that depend on with `add_dependencies`. Anyway, without modifying a target, you cannot use `target_compile_options`

Comment: What if you use more than a single compiler and need to set the flags differently for each of them ? What would be the way to do that properly, without direct call to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and CMAKE_C_FLAGS ?

Comment: Darn,, Was hoping you wouldn't say that. haha. Looks like it's time to start using cmake to generate projects instead of using it to write pre gradle scripts. I'll give ya the upvote cause cause you're right about leaving compiler flags alone. Turns into a nightmare. and you like TOOL. Seen em 32 times. oh.. By the way, you can still use -C myfile.cmake @ command line to alter just about any part of the cache variables you want before script loads if ya need a quick fix. Not that anybody should ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the command-line syntax specified by @Svalorzen, you could write a script that interprets its command-line arguments the way you like and converts them to something you can put on the cmake.exe command line.  If portability is a concern, you could write the script in a language such as Perl (generally available on Unix-like platforms and can be installed on Windows).

If all this is going to buy you is an alternative solution to the problem you described, however, I would recommend just using the answer from @Svalorzen.